# passing a swt Canvas to c++

Tags: java, java-native-interface, c++-cli, swt

i have a c++ programme to load video and i want to get this video in an interface java so i proceed with jni

this is my java code:

```
Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Example");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        // Create a canvas
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
        shell.setSize(580, 350);
        shell.open();
        int i = canvas.handle;
       //start( canvas.handle );
```

and this is my c++ code:

```
Console::WriteLine("0");
            m_ctrl = gcnew AxVideoRecvCtrl();
            Console::WriteLine("1");
            m_ctrl->Name = "VideoRecvCtrlLive";
            m_ctrl->BeginInit();
            Console::WriteLine("idCanvas = "+idCanvas);
            //
            IntPtr windowHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            m_ctrl->Parent = control->FromHandle((IntPtr)(idCanvas));

            if(m_ctrl->Parent == nullptr){
                Console::WriteLine("Is NULll");
                return;
            }
```

the problem is that always i get NULL result, any help please??